# ContentText is not a valid member of Player "Players.Player"

Tags: lua, scripting, roblox

I was trying to change a value to what was typed in the Message box, but it gave me error 'ContentText is not a valid member of Player "Players.Player"'

local script:

```
local event = game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage').BanUser

local plr = game:GetService('Players').LocalPlayer

local target = script.Parent.Parent.UsernameBox

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
    script.Parent.Parent.Visible = false
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Optional.Visible = true
    
    event:FireServer(plr,target)
    
    script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Ban.Value = true
end)
```

Server script:

```
local event1 = game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage').BanUser

event1.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(plr,target)
    plr.PlayerGui.BanUI.UI.userName.Value = target.ContentText
    print('time to die buddy')
end)
```

Comment: More information is required. What is target, what is Content text, what where is this script?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I see two errors I would like to address.

**1 - Player Input**
In your script I see that you want to send data through an event to the server side, however you are sending the variable `target`. Target is calling the the ui object of `UsernameBox`. To fix this you need to add `.Text` which gets the TextInput of the LocalPlayer. Code:

```
local target = script.Parent.Parent.UsernameBox.Text -- Adding .Text to get the PlayerText
```

**Sending RemoteEvent with plr object**
When firing an event from LocalScript, on the receiving end you can just call the player object and you don't have to include it when firing the event.

Local Script Example

```
event:FireServer(example)
```

Server Script Example

```
event.OnServer:Connect(function(plr, example)
-- Your Code Here
end)
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It doesn't give me the error anymore, but it doesn't set the value to the text.

Comment: Did you follow the answer I gave?

Comment: Yes i did i don't know why it isn't working